# Avoiding pop-up when having multiple hyperlink layers in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, hyperlink

In ArcMap 10.0, I have a layer of country polygons and a layer of city points. Both layers have a hyperlink setup, and it all works as expected. The only drawback is that when I select a city, it comes up with a pop-up asking whether I want to go the hyperlink of that city or to the hyperlink of the underlying country.

Is there any way of avoiding this pop-up, so that it goes to the city hyperlink when I click within x pixels of a city, and goes to the country hyperlink when I click elsewhere within the polygon.

---

I recently upgraded to ArcGIS v10.2, but the same functionality still exists. And based on the responses so far, I probably didn't explain my question very well.

First of all, I am not talking about a bug or error. The functionality is as expected, but I am looking for a way to overrule the default functionality.

Secondly, for simplicity I used countries and cities, but in reality it was contaminated sites (polygons) and borehole locations (points). The problem however doesn't change.

Below is an ArcGIS screenshot, showing the hyperlinked points inside the hyperlinked polygons.
[image: Hyperlinked Points inside Hyperlinked Polygons]

- When I click inside the polygon away from a point, it goes straight to the polygon's hyperlink. This is what I want.
- When I click on a point that is not inside a polygon, it goes straight to the point's hyperlink. Again, this is what I want.
- When I click on a point inside the polygon, it comes up with the hyperlinks selection box shown in the screenshot, asking whether I want the point's or the polygon's hyperlink. This what I expect and it is conform the specifications, but its NOT what I really want. I want it to go straight to the point's hyperlink and ignore the underlying polygon, because the point layer is the uppermost layer of the two.

Is this easily doable, or would I have to design a complex Python function? Given that this is such a negligible inconvenience, it's not worth to alter this. But if there's a quick tip, I'd happy to hear.

Comment: Just in case it helps, the hyperlinks work fine when clicking the city feature located on top of the country polygon for me. I use ArcMap 10.2.

Comment: Maybe you could share the HTML Popup tab configuration in a screenshot?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov: (don't know how to include a screenshot, so apologies for keeping it all verbal)
The hyperlink setup is totally standard. I have two gdb layers as described, one polygon layer and one point layer, each having a Text*255 field that holds a folder name, and which has been setup as the hyperlink field. Click in a polygon (away from any point), there is no ambiguity for ArcGIS, and it simply opens the specified folder. But click on a point, which is inside the hyperlinked polygon, and ArcGIS doesn't know whether you want to open the point or the  polygon hyperlink.

Comment: The above is all standard functionality, so maybe I'm asking something that's not easy or pretty impossible. But I would like to find out whether it's possible to ignore the underlying polygon hyperlink when clicking on a point.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov I think you should write up an Answer of "fixed at or before 10.2".  If the asker wishes to remain at 10.0 then I guess he/she has the option of asking Esri Support to backport the fix to a 10.0 Service Pack but I cannot see that happening with 10.3 now on the horizon.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are encountering software functionality which is working as designed.

Consequently, if you wish to have the specification for that functionality enhanced then I think you will need to submit an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/).